# Spring app under Tomcat cannot parse a json object sent to the server

Tags: java, json, spring, tomcat

I have an application which has been returning json objects from the server to the client properly for quite a while so I know my json filter is workign correctly.  However, when I try to send a json object via an Extjs Request my server cannon receive it.  Here's my request on the client side:

```
var pdfStore = Ext.StoreMgr.lookup('PDFStore');
pdfStore.loadData([],false);
pdfStore.add(Ext.create('PeakDayNew.model.PDFModel', {
    windSolarAllTimePeakList: Ext.pluck(WindSolarAllTimePeaksStore.data.items, 'data')
}));
var json = Ext.encode(Ext.pluck(pdfStore.data.items, 'data'));
console.log(json);
var myUrl = 'http://localhost:8080/PeakDaySvc/createpdf.json?queryDate=' +        
tradeDateInputValue + "&capMarginText=" + capMarginTextValue + 
"&taText=" + marketIssuesTextValue;

Ext.Ajax.request({
    timeout: 240000,
    url: myUrl,
    jsonData: json,
    scope: this,
    success: function(conn, response, options, eOpts) {
         myMask.hide();
         alert("Success");
[and so on . . . ]
```

And here is my server side which is a Spring app written in Java

```
@RequestMapping(value="/createpdf.json", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public PdfData getPDF(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
                            @RequestParam String queryDate, 
                            @RequestParam String capMarginText, 
                            @RequestParam String taText,
                            @RequestBody  PdfDataList pdfDataList) throws   DocumentException, IOException, NamingException, ParseException{
```

The javascript PDFStore object is just holder for a PDFModel object which is simply a collection of list.

Ext.define('PeakDayNew.model.PDFModel', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

```
requires: [
    'Ext.data.Field'
],

fields: [
    {
        name: 'daPeakAndMinForecastModelList',
        type: 'auto'
    },
    {
        name: 'windSolarAllTimePeakList',
        type: 'auto'
    },
and so on . . .
```

The object I'm expecting to receive on the server side, the PdfDataList, is just a wrapper of list.

```
public class PdfDataList  extends ArrayList<PDFModel>{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
}
```

And it's PDFModel matches the set of list in the javascript object.

```
public class PDFModel implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -873079502797637977L;

    private List<DAPeakAndMinForecastModel> daPeakAndMinForecastModelList;
    private List<StandardModel> windSolarAllTimePeakList;
and so on with all the setter/getters.
```

This architecture is working perfectly in another application we've written.  I'm building this app in Eclipse using a Tomcat 7.0 server and my guess is that there's some library that's missing in my tomcat setup because I can send json objects, but tomcat responds with a 400 Bad Request even though if I inspect the payload in the post it is a valid json object.

Also if I change my controller to accept not a @RequestBody  PdfDataList pdfDataList but a @RequestBody  String pdfDataList then I see the text of the json object.  That, and the inspection of the request payload,  tells me that my client side is building the json object properly.

Does anyone have any idea why my Spring app under Tomcat cannot parse the json object?

Comment: So, no error messages on the server side?  And it's impossible to examine the JSON received by the server to see if it's valid?

Comment: That is true Hot Licks.  I can put a breakpoint at the first line of my controller and it never gets there.  The Tomcat error log doesn't show anything and my application log only shows a POST with a 400 return code form the server.

Comment: To minimize the possible problem areas I made a simple PDFTestModel with 3 strings called Test1, Test2, Test3 and matched it on the server side.  The same 400 error occurs.  I did this just to verify that there's not some weird error in my json which doesn't match what I'm trying to receive on my server side.

Comment: Maybe you should double-check your URL, to make sure it's aimed at the right server.

Comment: OK, we found something, and it's odd.   In the server side PDFModel we removed the access indicator "private" in front of the field declarations and removed the "extends Serializable" and we can now receive an empty PDFModel object.   The loading of the model should be done via the getter/setter methods rather than the fields themselves so that's odd that it made a difference.  However, if I load data into the object it fails once again.  This point to a data type mismatch between the client and the server objects.  But removing the private modifier in the PDFModel was a strange way to fix it.